# Multithreading returns number before it finished processing (JAVA)

Tags: java, multithreading

I wrote the piece of code below to try to understand multithreading. However, the outcome is not what I expected. It seems like it returns the value before the search finishes executing. How can I make it wait until the result is ready and then only get the returned value?

```
/******************************************************************************

                            Online Java Compiler.
                Code, Compile, Run and Debug java program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to execute it.

*******************************************************************************/
import java.util.concurrent.Executor;  
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;  
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;  
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;  
import java.util.ArrayList;

//Finding the smallest number in an array
public class Main
{
    public static class Search implements Runnable {
        private int[] array;
        private int lowestNumber; 
        private int taskNumber;

        public Search(int[] array, int taskNumber){
            this.lowestNumber = 0;
            this.taskNumber = taskNumber;
            this.array = array;
        }

        public int getLowestNumber(){
            return lowestNumber;
        }

        protected void setLowestNumber(int lowestNumber){
            this.lowestNumber = lowestNumber;
        }

        protected void searchArrayLowestNumber(){
            int lowestValue = 0; 
            int arrayLength = array.length;

            for(int i = 0; i < arrayLength; i++){
                if( i == 0 ){
                    lowestValue = array[i];
                }
                if(array[i] < lowestValue){
                    lowestValue = array[i];
                } 
                System.out.println("array[i] lowestValue: " + lowestValue);
            }
            setLowestNumber(lowestValue);

        }

        public void run(){
                System.out.println("Accessing search...task number: " + taskNumber);
                searchArrayLowestNumber();

        }

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = (ThreadPoolExecutor) Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        int[][] arrayA = {{12, 13, 1}, {10, 34, 1}};

        for (int i = 0; i <= 1; i++) 
        {
            int[] tempArray = new int[3];
            for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++){
                tempArray[j] = arrayA[i][j];
            }
            Search searchLowestNumber = new Search(tempArray, i);
            int number = searchLowestNumber.getLowestNumber();
             try{
                Long duration = (long) (Math.random() * 10);
                System.out.println("Lowest number for this thread " + i + " is " + number);
                TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(duration); 
             }catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
             }

            executor.execute(searchLowestNumber);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

The current outcome is as following:

```
Lowest number for this thread 0 is 0                                                                                                                                               
Lowest number for this thread 1 is 0                                                                                                                                               
Accessing search...task number: 0                                                                                                                                                  
array[i] lowestValue: 12                                                                                                                                                           
array[i] lowestValue: 12                                                                                                                                                           
array[i] lowestValue: 1                                                                                                                                                            
Accessing search...task number: 1                                                                                                                                                  
array[i] lowestValue: 10                                                                                                                                                           
array[i] lowestValue: 10                                                                                                                                                           
array[i] lowestValue: 1
```

I'm actually expecting both the threads to return 1 at the end.

Comment: isn't both the Threads returning 1 at the end, if you observe the output?, If you need result only when both the threads are completed, that can be done but need some clarification for that

Comment: it is but I want it to return to the main correctly and have the number printed as it should in main.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two things you need to fix on it
First you have your print statement `System.out.println("array[i] lowestValue: " + lowestValue);` inside your for loop but outside your if conditional, so it is printing the current value of the `lowestValue` once for each element in the array, if you want that to be only printed when the variable is updated you should move that inside your if statement.

Second you have to move this expression `System.out.println("Lowest number for this thread " + i + " is " + number);` to after you call `executor.execute(searchLowestNumber);` since is there that the search is actually happening, other wise the number that you will be printing is the one that you are setting in the constructor of your class '0' since it has not been updated at that point